# Array en php solo devuelve la última posición

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array en php el cual lo codifico en un json. El dilema es que solo me está devolviendo la ultima de la lista.

> "{"data":{"prg":"PROGRESIVO: 1","val":"VALOR: 1","hora":"HORA: 15:08:16","fecha":"FECHA: 2020-06-02"}}"

¿Cómo hago para que me salgan todos los de la lista con ese mismo formato json?

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

$Sql_Query_0= "select prg,val,hora,fecha from lista";
$result = $con->query($Sql_Query_0);

if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query_0))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $prg= $row["prg"];
        $val= $row["val"];
        $hora= $row["hora"];
        $fecha= $row["fecha"];
        $valores ["data"]= array([
            'prg' => 'PROGRESIVO: '.$prg,
            'val' => 'VALOR: '.$val,
            'hora' => 'HORA: '.$hora,
            'fecha' => 'FECHA: '.$fecha 
        ]);
    }
}
else{


}

echo json_encode($valores);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta agregar el indice al arreglo `$valores`, agrega [] despues del indice `data`

```
 $valores ["data"][]= array([
        'prg' => 'PROGRESIVO: '.$prg,
        'val' => 'VALOR: '.$val,
        'hora' => 'HORA: '.$hora,
        'fecha' => 'FECHA: '.$fecha 
]);
```

También te recomiendo quitar el indice dentro de array([]) para que la lectura sea más fácil (quitar los corchetes).

Comment: Eso era muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 2):

Para esto hay que usar `array_push(array,datos)` y declarar la variable `valores` fuera y antes del `while`:

```
$Sql_Query_0= "select prg,val,hora,fecha from lista";
$result = $con->query($Sql_Query_0);

$valores = array();

if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query_0))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        array_push($valores, [
            'prg' => 'PROGRESIVO: '. $row["prg"],
            'val' => 'VALOR: '     . $row["val"],
            'hora' => 'HORA: '     . $row["hora"],
            'fecha' => 'FECHA: '   . $row["fecha"] 
        ]);
    }
}
echo json_encode($valores);
```